# Firefox extension to reload page when failed

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, add-on

I am trying to make a super tiny extension to wait 30 seconds and reload a page in case for any unspecific reason page couldn't load (timeouts, network instability...)

I am following [Mozilla's Your first extension](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Your_first_WebExtension). So far, so good. I did that work.

However, when I am using their methods, specifically [onErrorOccurred](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/webNavigation/onErrorOccurred), I can't register that event instead of following the guide.

I tried disconnecting my own wifi network and try accessing a random site. I couldn't see any logging.

What am I doing wrong?

If my approach is not correct, How should I do it?

**manifest.json**

```
{

  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "ElEspia",
  "version": "0.0.1",

  "description": "Watchdog for kiosk-like systems browser based",

  "icons": {
    "48": "icons/icon.png"
  },

  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": ["watchdog.js"]
    }
  ]

}
```

**watchdog.js**

```
document.body.style.border = "5px solid red";



function logOnErrorOccurred(details) {
  console.log(`onErrorOccurred: ${details.url}`);
  console.log(details.error);
}

console.log("Registered");

browser.webNavigation.onErrorOccurred.addListener(logOnErrorOccurred);
```

Comment: Content scripts can't use most of `browser` API. Content scripts run in web pages. You need a background script and also add webNavigation to permissions in manifest.json, see their demo extensions and the documentation.

Comment: Thanks for the info. But just these 2 changes doesn't seem to be enough. Any additional idea?

Comment: Naturally you would need to move the listener function as well. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38920982) on how to open devtools for the background script so you can debug it properly.

Comment: Thank you very very much. You pointed me in the right direction. I cannot empathized how much I appreciated.